# How to import csv to logstash using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to read and parse csv file using .net core and then send the bulk data to logstash.
I am not having problem with reading csv file (using CSVHelper) in my .net application.

I do not need to send data to Elastic, only to logstash because we have multiple teams in our company that are using logstash to filter and import data to elastic.

What I can find online are examples on how to import data to elastic directly or by using logstash to elastic but I am not able to find a way to use .net core project to import csv to logstash only.

My .net app is reading csv, filtering some columns, and then should send data in bulk to logstash.
Any help or suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: write to a file, then have logstash read the file? (also you could have read the csv directly with logstash)

Comment: reading from a file just to write to a file only for logstash to be able to read it doesn't seems like a smart way to go. I know I could read CSV directly with a logstash but I need to read it using .net and then send it to logstash.

Comment: You should take a look at the available [inputs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) and choose one that fit your needs. I talked about files because it's a common use case for logstash, so it's well-supported

Comment: thank you @baudsp, that seems very helpful.